# Wicket Application: Image interpreted as text/html

Tags: java, image, wicket, wicket-6

In my application I load images from the database into a Wicket Image Object and display it. This works most of the times, but has some nasty side effects (images within the list swap sometimes, a js error in the console )

The **error** I get is:

```
Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html
```

this is my **java**:

```
final IResource imageResource = new DynamicImageResource() {
    @Override
    protected byte[] getImageData(final IResource.Attributes attributes) {
        return bean.getImage();
    }
};
```

and my **html**

```
<img wicket:id="image">
```

this is the html code thats rendered out in the browser:

```
<img src="./.?308-IResourceListener-homePanel-tabPanel-tabs-panel-data-rows-3-image">
```

I checked the tomcat's web.xml for mime-mapping -> all image types (png, jpg are correct). I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Anyone has an idea?

I use Wicket 6.16.0, Tomcat 7.0.54

Answer (score 1):

You could try to override in your `DynamicImageResource` `configureResponse()` or `setResponseHeaders()` and set the Content Type manually on the `ResourceResponse` using `response.setContentType("yourContentType");`

Answer (score 0):

Your `getImage()` probably returns `null`

This is what happens in `DynamicImageResource`

```
@Override
protected ResourceResponse newResourceResponse(final Attributes attributes)
{
    ...

    if (response.dataNeedsToBeWritten(attributes))
    {
        ....

        final byte[] imageData = getImageData(attributes);
        if (imageData == null)
        {
            response.setError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND);
        }
        else
        {
            response.setContentType("image/" + getFormat());
            response.setWriteCallback(new WriteCallback()
            {
                @Override
                public void writeData(final Attributes attributes)
                {
                    attributes.getResponse().write(imageData);
                }
            });

            configureResponse(response, attributes);
        }
        ...
```

So the mimetype will get set to `getFormat()` which defaults to PNG.